# windows Cmd freezes and I have to click on window to coninue

Tags: ruby, cmd

I have a ruby script that displays it's progress via the cmd and completes in about 10 minutes. In the last few weeks the cmd seems to freeze and after 10 minutes when I click on the cmd window it then completes the script. 
I have searched on forums and suggestions include: disable QuickEdit Mode & Insert Mode which I have done but this has not fixed the problem.

The platform is an azure windows server 2016 VM.
Could this problem be due to a recent windows update?

Thanks

Comment: `return question.has_example_code? ? "We can help!" : "...."`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the usual Windows Command Window, Ruby has no way of knowing that you have clicked into the Window, so it is unlikely that it is related to the code. However, Windows *does* block a command to write to the command window on certain circumstances, and if this happens, Ruby waits on, say, `STDOUT.puts`, until it is allowed to continue. Of course this applies not only to Ruby, but to any application writing to the command console.

The most typical situation, in which this occurs, is, if you (maybe accidentally) select with the mouse something in the console Window. The script running in the console is blocked. By clicking with the mouse inside the window, the selection is cancelled, and the program continues to run.

Comment: This behavior is controlled by the "QuickEdit Mode" under "Properties" respective "Defaults"  (a very helpful option when you are aware of this behavior)

Comment: I have already disabled this option but this was unable to fix the problem

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a different console program? For instance, try [Console 2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/console-devel/2.00/). For the safe side, check in Settings/Behaviour the options *Copy on select* and *Clear selection on copy*; I think they are off by default.